# Why would one want to put a unary plus (+) operator in front of a C++ lambda?

Tags: c++, lambda

I found out that in C++ we can use `+` in lambda function `+[]{}`
Example from the article:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
int main()
{
    auto funcPtr = +[] {};
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(funcPtr), void (*)()>::value);
}
```

The main idea of + sign in lambda

> You can force the compiler to generate lambda as a function pointer rather than closure by adding + in front of it as above.

But what are advantages of using '+' in lambda? Could you please provide example or link me to the explanation?

Comment: Note that this conversion only works if lambda has no captures

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not a feature of lambda and more is a feature of implicit type conversion.

What happens there is stemming from the fact that a captureless lambda *can* be implicitly converted to a pointer to function with same signature as lambda's `operator()`. `+[]{}` is an expression where unary `+`  is a no-op , so the only legal result of expression is a pointer to function.

In result `auto funcPtr` would be a pointer to a function, not an instance of an object with anonymous type returned by lambda expression. Not much of advantage in provided code, but it can be important in type-agnostic code, e.g. where some kind of `decltype` expression is used. E.g.

```
#include <type_traits>

void foo(int);

template<class T>
struct is_foo : std::is_same<T, decltype(&foo)> {};

int main()
{
    auto foo1 = +[](int)->void {};
    auto foo2 = [](int)->void {};
    static_assert(is_foo<decltype(foo1)>::value, "foo1 is not like foo");
    static_assert(is_foo<decltype(+foo2)>::value, "+foo2 is not like foo");
    static_assert(is_foo<decltype(foo2)>::value, "foo2 is not like foo"); 
}
```

Note that you can do same with `foo`:  `std::is_same<T, decltype(+foo)> {};`

Albeit some platforms may not support that, because they inherently may have a variety of function pointers with different calling convention and the expression will be ambiguous.

Answer (score 6):

One advantage to use function pointer against lambda in template might be to reduce the number of template instantiation.

```
template <typename F>
void f(F func) { func(); }


int main()
{
    f([](){});  // f<lambda_1>
    f([](){});  // f<lambda_2>
    f(+[](){}); // f<void(*)()>
    f(+[](){}); // f<void(*)()>
}
```

Comment: ooh, right   C++ now allows to use lambda like in template arguments even. Maybe it could be better for our sanity that it wouldn't. I sense birth of so many bugs related to *this* and millions of my brain cells scream in horror.

Comment: Using lambda in template is so convenient.

Comment: The advantage of inferring a specific lambda type as a template parameter is that invocation of the lambda can be inlined and optimized.  This is how C++ often gets the same or better performance from functional-style code as from explicit hand-written loops.

Comment: @BenVoigt Through tracing the value and (if needed) function duplication it can nearly always be inlined and optimized. But yes, using a lambda makes it nearly guaranteed.